# Ceiling fan (2 wires to 6 wires)

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Replacing an existing ceiling fan. Single pole switch.

Goal: it works… flip the switch on fan and light come on. Control setting through the remote.

Junction box has ground, 2 blacks twisted with a white, 2 whites, and single black.

New fan has: black and white

Which ones should be connected. Pictured the new mount is already on ceiling with grounds connected. Capped the others as they were connected to old fan that the switch only controlled the light (pull chain fan)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Usually there's 3 wires + ground in a fan/light combo.

Comment: OP stated they will use remote to control light vs. fan, which is quite common these days.

Comment: @Kori Do you have a make/model # of the fan? That would help verify that the connections.

Comment: @Criggie OP stated *Control setting through the remote.*

Answer (score 2):

Next time, take pictures before you disconnect anything. Makes it a **lot** easier.

But in this case, it *should* be:

- (1) Black = switched hot from switch (if you trace the wires, you should find it is paired with the white of "blacks + white")
- (2) Blacks + white = incoming hot (black), outgoing to elsewhere hot (black), hot to switch (white)
- (3) Whites = incoming neutral, outgoing to elsewhere neutral

You can verify easily enough - with everything as shown and breaker on, you should find power on the blacks+white but nowhere else, and on the single black when you turn the switch on. But don't test that way unless you are really sure how to do this safely using a non-contact tester.

- (4) Connect fan black to single black
- (5) Connect fan white to whites

You will need wire nuts for: 1 + 4, 2 (by itself), 3 + 5.

All grounds always together.

Comment: You're spot on according to the pictures, but I think another wire or two will appear when he starts assembling -- adding on the light fixture.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore The new fixture has black and white wires, 4 & 5 in picture 2, and I included those in my answer.

Comment: I know, and I acknowledged that as "Spot on". That's what the pic shows.  However,  In my experience, Fan/lights usually have separate power - Always hot to the fan, and switched to the light.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Or two switched hots, so you can control fan and light independently from the wall. Model # would help so we could verify.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore this fan has a remote to control the fan & lights independently. All it needs is always on (or switched "always" on, in this case) to power the electronic receiver which then determines if the lights, fan, both or neither are on. All those additional wires are there, they're just hidden from the house wiring and controlled by the remote via relays.